# Rsyslog doesn't create log files on CentOS7

Tags: centos7, rsyslog

I have the following configuration file in "/etc/rsyslog.d/10-my.conf"

```
# This file is managed by Puppet, changes may be overwritten
if $programname == 'hello' then -/var/log/test/test.log
& ~
```

On CentOS6.5 (rsyslog **5.8.10** ) this creates an empty file in */var/log/test/test.log*
Same configuration file on CentOS7(rsyslog **7.4.7**) doesn't create an empty file.
 Anyone can tell why is that? Did this behavior change in 7.4? Or is it something on my CentOS7 instance?
rsyslogd -f/etc/rsyslog.d/10-my.conf -N3
On CentOS6 and CentOS7 returns whole bunch of warnings but nothing serious.
CentOS7 SELinux is set to Permissive mode
CentOS 7 (/etc/rsyslog.conf)

```
# file is managed by puppet
#################
#### MODULES ####
#################

$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging
$ModLoad imjournal # provides access to the systemd journal   

###########################
#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####
###########################
$MaxMessageSize 2k

#
# Set the default permissions for all log files.
#
$FileOwner root
$FileGroup root
$FileCreateMode 0600
$DirOwner root
$DirGroup root
$DirCreateMode 0750
$PrivDropToUser root
$PrivDropToGroup root
$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog
$Umask 0000

# Turn off message reception via local log socket;
# local messages are retrieved through imjournal now.
$OmitLocalLogging on

$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf

#
# Emergencies are sent to everybody logged in.
#
*.emerg :omusrmsg:*
```

Answer (score 0):

As expected it turns out that default behaviour changed in 7.4 and it doesn't create an empty file anymore, however works fine(e.g create a test.log file) if you test it using the following command:

```
logger -t hello "Test"
```

Version 5.8 does create an empty file but still works fine if this file(/var/log/test/test.log) was deleted.